# jquery regex split at wild card between number digits

Tags: jquery, regex

Currently I split a string by declaring the characters I wish to split at. The problem is I want to split at ANY character between number digits. I wish to use the `split()` function as apposed to regex function due to overhead.

DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/7pHj3/3/

```
var str = '14/12/17';
var str = str.split(/\/|\.|\-/g); // currently limited to '/ . -'

$('.piece1').text(str[0]);
$('.piece2').text(str[1]);
$('.piece3').text(str[2]);
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use the negated class `\D` (it will match anything but a digit):

```
var str = str.split(/\D+/g);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pHj3/3/)